# Is i3 540 compatable with foxconn 2abf

Tags: hard-drive

i am planning to buy i3-540, gt 730 2gb gdrr5 and 8 gb ddr3, i want to run-cod advanced warfare, naruto ultimate ninja storm 4,wwe2k15 and nfs rivals.
well there are 2 ques-
1. will i be able to run these games after upgrade?
2. Is i3 540 compatable with foxconn 2abf

Answer (score 2):

The Intel i3 540 processor appears to be a [socket 1156](http://ark.intel.com/products/46473/Intel-Core-i3-540-Processor-4M-Cache-3_06-GHz). The Foxconn 2ABF motherboard, on the other hand, [supports the 1155 socket](http://www.findlaptopdriver.com/specs-foxconn-2abf-motherboard-7252011h48/). These are not compatible, and it would be off-topic here for us to provide specific hardware requirements.

Comment: wait so means i have to look for another card, if so which one would be compatable with foxconn under 7000rs. ($105)

Comment: @pankajtekriwal Of course. You can't cram a square into a hole. They are different pin configurations

Comment: @Any 1155 socket cpu. Hardware recommendations are off topic as ChrisInEdmonton said

Comment: ok never mind tell me the 1st ques then please

Comment: 1st Ques? What do you mean by that

Comment: well then please read the point mentioned carefully it says (well there are 2 ques- 1. will i be able to run these games after upgrade? 2. Is i3 540 compatable with foxconn 2abf?)

Comment: The hardware requirements for those games are well documented.  You should be able to compare them to the hardware you wish to purchase (which are compatible with one another) yourself.  the proposed hardware is pretty bottom of the barrel for the programs you listed.